# Menu disappears when status portlet is active

Tags: permissions, liferay, customization, portlet

I'm using liferay 6.1.1 and when there is some permissions problem there is showing status page with content that informs me, that I haven't permission to see this resource. Unfortunately when status page is showing, menu disappears. How can I customize this page (statusPortlet?), to prevent menu disappear ?

Comment: What do you mean by menu? Can you  please  attach snapshot here?

Comment: Hi. I can't because it is on my locale machine. I mean that menu bar disappear, simply I launch status page and there is a page without menu bar